# Unable to create table through another table in oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqldatatypes

I have been trying to create a new table by using below query :

"Create table d1_details_test2
as
select * from d1_details"

this above query gives me an error :

[image]

actually "d1_details" table has one column which has "Long" datatype and i cannot change it.

so i want to know the any other way to create the table.

Thanks

Comment: If the goal is just to create the table, just `create table` and specify the other column names and data types explicitly

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Justin 
Yes goal is just to create a table. Actually i need to drop the table "d1_details", that's why i want to put the data into "d1_details_test2". then i will create again "d1_details" from the table "d1_details_test2".

There are four data type in this table  : 
varchar(255)
Char(1 Byte)
Long
datestamp

57 columns are varchar data type except five columns having other above mentioned data type.

Answer (score 1):

The `long` data type is subject to many restrictions. Create table as select is one of these.

You can get around it by applying `to_lob` in the `select`, which converts it to a `clob`:

```
create table views as
  select view_name, text from user_views;

ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
  
create table views as
  select view_name, to_lob ( text ) lob 
  from   user_views;

desc views

Name        Null?   Type            
VIEW_NAME           VARCHAR2(128)    
LOB                 CLOB
```